# Best way of storing data in 100 objects for later retrieval?

Tags: r

When doing sequencing, I normally apply `TraMineR`'s `seqdef` function on a dataset to generate a single sequence object:

```
sequence_object <- seqdef(data)
```

However, let's say I want to loop through a dataframe and generate 1 sequence object per every chunk of 10 columns. Then I would do something like this:

```
colpicks <- seq(10,1000,by=10)
mapply(function(start,stop) seqdef(df[,start:stop]), colpicks-9, colpicks)
```

Now, I want to store these objects in some suitable manner. Two questions:

1. What is the most suitable way of storing (or maybe just automatically naming) 100 objects, so that I can easily loop through each of them at a later point?
2. How can I modify my code above so that it stores the data per your answer to (1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Most suitable" is completely subjective and dependent on your goal.
I'm assuming this question is related to your previous question, and thus I would suggest setting the `simplify` argument of `mapply` to FALSE

```
myMatrixList <- mapply(.... , simplify=FALSE)
```

However, even that is not necessary, as you can just combine the `sapply` from the previous question and skip the middle step

Comment: So - every object can also be stored in 1 position per object in a list?

Comment: Also - I understand "most suitable" is very subjective. I was hoping that the context I provided in the question might help to decide what was most suitable in this situation. What other information should I provide to help determine what is "most suitable"?

Comment: Do you mean "1 object per position in the list"?

Comment: @histelheim, correct, one item (matrix or data frame) per list element, ie per "position" in the list.